# How to make MySQL Server > 5.5.45 on OS X Yosemite accessible through tcp?

Tags: mysql, configuration, database-connection, osx-yosemite

Right now I do a `netstat -n | grep 3306` and nothing come. Beside I try to connect using:

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

to connect and see the error below. Even so, when I use:

```
$ mysql -hlocalhost -u root -p
```

no problem at all to connect to the server.

All this indicated me that MySQL Server installed the official installer on OS X 10.10 Yosemite, not allow networks connection to the server. How I enable that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --port=3307` that is the command line set by the installer, and as you can see, the port is 3307, no 3306, that was the problem ;)